# why does this "4 | 2 | 4 | 1 | 10" return 15 in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I was just experimenting and tried putting this in the console:

```
4 | 2 | 4 | 1 | 10
```

returns **15** in console..

```
4 | 2 | 4 | 3 | 1
```

returns **7** in console..

I tried that on Chrome and Firefox.

**Why?**

*I'm just starting with learning JavaScript... maybe I'm missing a concept here?*

Comment: What were you expecting it to return, and why?

Comment: What do you expect it to return?

Comment: Well I've never worked with bitwise operators as the other folks mentioned below.. personally, I was expecting 'true', but this is JavaScript so I'm not used to its concepts and quirks yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `|` operator in JavaScript is a [bitwise integer OR operator](http://es5.github.com/#x11.10). So it's doing an OR operation on the bits you're giving it, resulting in 15.

A [bitwise OR operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#OR) takes each bit in the value and sets the corresponding bit in the result if *either* of the input bits in that position is set. So

```
4  is 0100 in binary
2  is 0010
4  is 0100
1  is 0001
10 is 1010
      ----
      1111 = 15 decimal
```

**Update**: In a comment on your question, you've said you were expecting `true` rather than `15`. If so, you want the *logical* OR operator, `||`, not the bitwise operator, although `||` may also surprise you with what it returns (`4 || 2 || 4 || 1 || 10 = 4`, not `true`), as JavaScript's logical OR (`||`) is [curiously powerful](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/javascripts-curiously-powerful-or.html), more so than in many other languages.

Comment: Yes... in binary it makes lots of sense: 0100 | 0010 | 0100 | 0001 | 1010 = 1111 = 15

Comment: @JanCarloViray: Probably millions of them. Bitwise operations are very popular in computing. Probably not *as* popular in the typical environment where JavaScript is used (web browsers), but I'm sure there are some. And certainly when JavaScript is used in other environments, such as NodeJS where you do operations like open files and use the `|` to combine the various file mode flags.

Comment: Not really in javascript, but, in embedded programming. YES. In fact, bit masking (using OR and AND effectively) is one of the first things taught in any embedded programming book/class.

Answer (score 3):

You're using an [OR operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation)

If you want a true/false or, you'll want ||.

Comment: Note, using the logical `||` operator is not going to result in either `true` or `false` with those integer operands. Both cases will simply result in `4`

Comment: I know, but, if he wants true/false.

Comment: @DhaivatPandya: Again, Phil's point is that `||` won't give you `true` or `false` either.

Comment: Ah, now that I read it again makes sense. What I meant to say was if you wanted to find out whether or not somethings are true when ORed in the English sense, you do not want to use the bit operator.

Answer (score 2):

The `|` operator is the **bitwise or** operator.

The `|` operator lines up the binary digits of each operand, and returns `1` for that place if there is a `1` in that place either or both of the operands.

For example, let's look at what `3 | 10` does:

`3` is `11` in binary.
`10` is `1010` in binary.

Line them up, and you get

```
3      - 0011
10     - 1010
Result - 1011
```

The result `1011` is `11` in decimal, so the result of this example is `11`.

Here's one of the examples in your question `4 | 2 | 4 | 1 | 10`

```
 4 - 0100
 2 - 0010
 4 - 0100
 1 - 0001
10 - 1010
 | ======
     1111
```

And `1111` is binary for `15`, which was the result you got.

The bitwise or operator, along with other [bit manipulation operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation) are generally used for low-level computations. For example, you can implement arithmetic like multiplication, addition, and division entirely with bitwise operators.